# LinkedIn API 403(Forbidden) on any request url including v2

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, linkedin-api

in ASP.NET MVC app I'm trying to use LinkedIn for user Authentication and get the user's full profile.

I'm usin OpenAuth (`DotNetOpenAuth` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth`)

## Request for User Data

```
  private const string UserInfoEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~" + Fields;

  var uri = BuildUri(UserInfoEndpoint, new NameValueCollection { { "oauth2_access_token", accessToken } }); 

  var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri); 
        using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
        using (var stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (stream == null)
                return null; 
            using (var textReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var xml = textReader.ReadToEnd();

                var extraData = XElement.Parse(xml)
                .Elements()
                .ToDictionary(
                    el => el.Name.LocalName,
                    el => el.Value
                ); 
                extraData.Add("accesstoken", accessToken); 
                return extraData;
            }
        }
```

This making a successful get of user basic data. but when I change the url like below then it returning `403 Forbidden`

```
private const string UserInfoEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/~" + Fields;
```

or

```
private const string UserInfoEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me/?";
```

I noticed about partnership program, Is that what I need to access these url's? or what is really wrong here?
[This docs about the v2 API but nothing about partnership program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/consumer/context)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using V1 ( till 1st march ) then this is valid :
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~ 
This url is related to r_basicprofile

if you are moving to V2 then you can't use this url because in V2 you have to take permission from linked to use r_basicprofile

in V2 you can use : r_liteprofile for firstName,lastName,profilePicture,id
 r_emailaddress for getting emailAddress

Check this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context